# $s-$fractional Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $$u(x) = \dfrac{1}{|x|^{N-2s}},N \neq 2s.$$ I want to show that
$(-\Delta)^s u(x) = 0,\forall x \neq 0$, where $(-\Delta)^s $ is the $s-$fractional Laplacian, defined by

$$(-\Delta)^s u(x) := C(N,s) \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^N \backslash B(x,\varepsilon)} \dfrac{u(x)-u(y)}{|x-y|^{N+2s}}dy.$$
There are many proofs using Fourier transform. However, I am looking for a "more elementary" proof. Can someone help me?

Thank for your help.

Comment: You could use the Caffarelli-Silvestre method of going through $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$. For $s=\frac12$, that reduces to the ordinary Dirichlet-to-Neumann map, and the harmonic extension is easy. For general $s$ I don't know how difficult it is. Anyway, this is probably not "elementary" either.